# Fix lag on indicator

Tags: pine-script, trading, tradingview-api, pine-script-v5

I recently found this indicator that detects sweeps followed by a MSB break. Only problem I have is it sometimes has a leg of 5 to sometimes 15 bars of lag before showing up on the screen. I tried looking through the code but couldnt really find the problem.

Anybody can help me on what needs to be fixed?

```
indicator("Quasimodo Pattern", "QML", overlay=true, max_bars_back=5000, max_labels_count=500, max_lines_count=500)

zigzag_len = input.int(5, "ZigZag Length")
//pivotLookup  = input.int(defval=1, minval=1, maxval=5,title='Pivot Lookup', tooltip='Minimum = 1, Maximum = 5')
var float[] high_points_arr = array.new_float(5)
var int[] high_index_arr = array.new_int(5)
var float[] low_points_arr = array.new_float(5)
var int[] low_index_arr = array.new_int(5)

to_up = high >= ta.highest(zigzag_len)
to_down = low <= ta.lowest(zigzag_len)

trend = 1
trend := nz(trend[1], 1)
trend := trend == 1 and to_down ? -1 : trend == -1 and to_up ? 1 : trend

last_trend_up_since = ta.barssince(to_up[1])
low_val = ta.lowest(nz(last_trend_up_since > 0 ? last_trend_up_since : 1, 1))
low_index = bar_index - ta.barssince(low_val == low)

last_trend_down_since = ta.barssince(to_down[1])
high_val = ta.highest(nz(last_trend_down_since > 0 ? last_trend_down_since : 1, 1))
high_index = bar_index - ta.barssince(high_val == high)

if ta.change(trend) != 0
    if trend == 1 //Down
        array.push(low_points_arr, low_val)
        array.push(low_index_arr, low_index)
    if trend == -1 //Up
        array.push(high_points_arr, high_val)
        array.push(high_index_arr, high_index)


f_get_high(ind) =>
    [array.get(high_points_arr, array.size(high_points_arr) - 1 - ind), array.get(high_index_arr, array.size(high_index_arr) - 1 - ind)]


f_get_low(ind) =>
    [array.get(low_points_arr, array.size(low_points_arr) - 1 - ind), array.get(low_index_arr, array.size(low_index_arr) - 1 - ind)]


[h0, h0i] = f_get_high(0)
[l0, l0i] = f_get_low(0)
[h1, h1i] = f_get_high(1)
[l1, l1i] = f_get_low(1)
[h2, h2i] = f_get_high(2)
[l2, l2i] = f_get_low(2)

bu_cond = trend == -1 and h2 > h1 and l1 > l0 and h0 > h1 //and close > h1
be_cond = trend == 1 and l2 < l1 and h1 < h0 and l0 < l1 //and close < l1

if bu_cond and not bu_cond[1]
    //line.new(h2i, h2, l1i, l1, color=color.green, width=2)
    line.new(l1i, l1, h1i, h1, color=color.green, width=2)
    line.new(h1i, h1, l0i, l0, color=color.green, width=2)
    line.new(l0i, l0, h0i, h0, color=color.green, width=2)
    line.new(l1i, l1, bar_index, l1, color=color.green, width=2)
    label.new(bar_index, l1, "Bull BB", style=label.style_label_up, textcolor=color.white, color=color.green, size=size.tiny)
    alert("Bullish QM!", alert.freq_once_per_bar)

if be_cond and not be_cond[1]
    //line.new(l2i, l2, h1i, h1, color=color.red, width=2)
    line.new(h1i, h1, l1i, l1, color=color.red, width=2)
    line.new(l1i, l1, h0i, h0, color=color.red, width=2)
    line.new(h0i, h0, l0i, l0, color=color.red, width=2)
    line.new(h1i, h1, bar_index, h1, color=color.red, width=2)
    label.new(bar_index, h1, "Bear BB", style=label.style_label_down, textcolor=color.white, color=color.red, size=size.tiny)
    alert("Bearish BB!", alert.freq_once_per_bar)
```

[What it looks like on TV](https://www.tradingview.com/x/Xb3AayB2/)